# Java split() regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I like to split a string into an array by using the split(regex) function.

I want to split it on semicolons `;` - but there are also "escaped" semicolons in the String (`\;`) which should not be used for the split.

Is there a regex for the `.split(regex)` function that would do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `negative look-behind` to split on `semi-colon` not preceded by `\\`: -

```
str.split("(?<!\\\\);");
```

You need to use `4 backslashes` - escape a backslash once for Java, and then escape the 2 backslashes again for regex.